# Zero divisors in $\{[a]+[b]\sqrt{3}\mid [a],[b]\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my exam I was asked to find which of the following is not a zero divisor:

1. $[1]+[2]\sqrt{3}$
2. $[5]+[1]\sqrt{4}$
3. $[5]+[4]\sqrt{3}$
4. $[6]+[1]\sqrt{3}$
5. $[9]+[4]\sqrt{3}$

in the ring $\{ [a]+[b]\sqrt{3}\mid [a],[b]\in\mathbb{Z}_{11} \}$ with the binary operations

$$([a]+[b]\sqrt{3})+([c]+[d]\sqrt{3})=[a+c]+[b+d]\sqrt{3}$$ and

$$([a]+[b]\sqrt{3})([c]+[d]\sqrt{3})=([ac]+[3bd])+([ad]+[bc])\sqrt{3}$$

What is the sound method to solve this problem? In the exam I could not think of a way to get the result easily so I just tried numbers but that proved to be quite difficult.

Comment: HInt: Consider their norm. What is it? What norm must (necessary condition) a zero divisor have?

Comment: Alternative hint if you don't know the norm, starting with what you wrote. You shown that for a zero-divisor, $ 0 \equiv ac+3bd \equiv ad + bc \pmod{11}$. Now show that 1/ If $ a= 0$ then $b= 0 $, 2/$ 0 \equiv 3bd^2  - bc^2$, 3/ So for a zero divisor, a necessary (but maybe not sufficient) condition is that $0 \equiv c^2 - 3d^2$.  4/ Identify which in the list are definitely not zero-divisors. 5/ For the rest, shown that they are indeed zero-divisors.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Begin with writing at least the definition of what a zero divisor is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a+b\sqrt{3}$ is a zero divisor if and only if the following system of equations:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}ac+3bd=0\\bc+ad=0\end{array}$$

has nontrivial solutions in $c,d$, which (as $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$ is a field) is equivalent to its *determinant* being zero, i.e.

$$\begin{vmatrix}a&3b\\b&a\end{vmatrix}=0$$

which is: $a^2-3b^2=0$ (in $\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$).

Knowing that, you can check that condition on your five examples.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use your second equation (the one for the multiplication) and plug the coefficients from your tests as $a$ and $b$. then you impose that both the integer part and the irrational part are 0 and see if you can find a solution that is not $c=d=0$.

For example, let's try $1 + 2\sqrt(3)$: To see if it's a divisor of zero we look for an elemnt $c+d\sqrt(3)$ that multiplied by $1 + 2\sqrt(3)$ is zero (mod 11).

The multiplication gives $c+6d + (d+2c)\sqrt(3)$. So we solve the system

- $c+6d=0\,\, (mod 11)$
- $d+2c=0 \,\, (mod 11)$
  That gives $d-12d = -11d= 0$ which is always true mod 11.

This means that we can find an element that multiplied by $1 + 2\sqrt(3)$ gives zero (i.e. every element in the form $-6d+d\sqrt(3)$, for example $-6+\sqrt(3)$